# Has it already been discussed in Congress about what to do with the Confederate statues at the Gettysburg National Military Park?

Tags: united-states, congress, procedure, monuments

I would like to know if it has already been discussed in Congress about what to do with the Confederate statues located at the Gettysburg National Military Park, or if there is a future date that has been set in which Congress will take up this issue.

Has it already been discussed in Congress about what to do with the Confederate statues at the Gettysburg National Military Park?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Has it already been discussed in Congress about what to do with the Confederate statues at the Gettysburg National Military Park?*

Not yet, within the 117th Congress (2021-2022). There is one bill that has been referred to the House Committee on Natural Resources, which then referred the bill to the [Subcommittee on National Parks, Forests, and Public Lands](https://naturalresources.house.gov/hearings). As of July 16, 2021, no hearings have been held and none were scheduled for this bill. The bill addresses all Confederate Monuments that fall within the Department of the Interior.

[H.R.672](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/672/text) - Rejecting and Eliminating the Foul Use of Symbols Exulting Confederate Principles Act

> To direct the Secretary of the Interior to establish a grant program to provide funds for the removal of Confederate symbols, and for other purposes.
>
> SEC. 5. DEFINITIONS.
>
> In this Act:
>
> (1) CONFEDERATE SYMBOL.—The term “Confederate symbol” includes—
>
> (A) a Confederate flag; or
>
> (B) a monument, memorial, statue, commemorative structure, symbol, or signage that honors a Confederate leader, Confederate soldier, the Confederate States of America, or the Confederacy in general.

A similar bill [H.R.8095](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/8095/text) was introduced in the 116th Congress. That bill "died" in committee. There were no hearings.

The National Park Service recognizes that legislation may be enacted affecting the monuments at Gettysburg.

[Confederate Monuments](https://www.nps.gov/gett/learn/historyculture/confederate-monuments.htm)

> Many commemorative works, including monuments and markers, were specifically authorized by Congress. In other cases, a monument may have preceded the establishment of a park, and thus could be considered a protected park resource and value. In either of these situations, legislation could be required to remove the monument, and the NPS may need to comply with Section 106 of the National Historic Preservation Act and the National Environmental Policy Act before removing a statue/memorial.

---

On July 14, 2020, H.R.7612 was placed on the House Calendar, but the bill never came up for a vote. Consequently, there was no discussion of the bill reported in the Congressional Record.

[H.R.7612](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/7612/text) - Department of the Interior, Environment, and Related Agencies Appropriations Act, 2021

> Sec. 442. Notwithstanding any other provision of law or policy to the contrary, within 180 days of enactment of this Act, the National Park Service shall remove from display all physical Confederate commemorative works, such as statues, monuments, sculptures, memorials, and plaques, as defined by NPS, Management Policies 2006, §9.6.1

A search of the *Congressional Record* didn't reveal any discussions about "Confederate symbols, monuments, or statues" during the 116th and 117th Congresses concerning Gettysburg or other parks or cemeteries.

The Congressional Research Service Report [Confederate Symbols: Relation to Federal Lands and Programs](https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/R/R44959/5), Updated July 28, 2020, contains additional information.